# Berkovich spaces — why use atlases?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, non-archimedean-fields, berkovich-geometry

Note: this question only concerns Berkovich spaces ("analytic spaces") as defined in Berkovich's first book "[Spectral Theory and Analytic Geometry over Non-Archimedean Fields](https://doi.org/10.1090/surv/033)", *not* any of the further developments of the theory. I will refer to this book throughout.

In pretty much all areas of modern algebraic geometry the predominating approach is through locally ringed spaces — we have some basic objects (affine varieties, affine schemes, affinoid spaces, …) equipped with a structure sheaf, and general objects are those locally isomorphic to the basic ones.

As I was learning about Berkovich spaces, I was intrigued to find out in his original book Berkovich takes a different approach using the language of atlases. My impression is that for e.g. the category of schemes, using atlases is an alternative, equivalent approach, but Berkovich seems to use *both* for reasons unclear to me.

Specifically, in the first two chapters of his book he develops the theory of affinoid spaces, and at the beginning of chapter 3 he defines quasiaffinoid spaces (open subspaces of affinoid ones), then moves on to general analytic spaces, which are defined as locally analytic spaces which are *additionally* equipped with an atlas provided by quasiaffinoid spaces. Hence the question:

> Why? What is the reason that Berkovich requires his analytic spaces to be additionally equipped with an atlas?

I can think of two reasons why this is the case:

- The first is that there may exist non-isomorphic analytic spaces which have the same underlying locally ringed space. In this case, an atlas is a genuinely necessary additional piece of structure.
- The second is that the atlas are only used to "correctly" define morphisms between Berkovich spaces. In this case atlases may be convenient, but they are not strictly necessary (since we can in principle recover an atlas from just the underlying ringed space). I suspect not all morphisms arise as simply morphisms of the underlying locally ringed spaces (unlike in the case of schemes or rigid spaces, say).

I am certain that Berkovich has good reasons to use these atlases, but again it is not clear which of the two reasons above, if either, is the cause.

Comment: If you allow non-strictly analytic spaces, then the forgetful functor to locally ringed spaces is not fully faithful. For example if $k$ is trivially valued and $0 < r < s < 1$, then the fields $K_r$ and $K_s$ from the example after Def. 2.1.1 agree as abstract $k$-algebras but not as Banach $k$-algebras. Therefore their spectra (which have just one point) agree as locally ringed spaces, but not as affinoid spaces.

Comment: You may also be interested in Temkin's Introduction to Berkovich Analytic Spaces, Section 4.1. There he gives a more intrinsic definition of the category of analytic spaces without using atlases.

Comment: @JakobWerner Thank you for your reply. Do you happen to know what happens if we only work over nontrivially valued fields, or only consider strictly $k$-analytic spaces? As for Temkin's notes, I'm afraid he *does* use atlases in definition 4.1.2.1, and I suspect there it is unavoidable due to the use of nets (this is why I am careful in my question to only talk about Berkovich's original book, which predates his notion of nets)

Comment: Ah, you're right about Temkin's notes. I only recalled that he gave a definition of _morphisms_ which avoids atlases. As far as I recall, strictly analytic spaces over a non-trivially valued field in the sense of the book embed fully faithfully into locally ringed spaces. The main point should be that algebra morphisms between strictly affinoid algebras are automatically continuous.